# NOT NULL constraint failed(code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have following table in Room database :

```
@Entity(tableName = "goals")
class SavingsGoalWrapper(
    @PrimaryKey val primaryKey: String = "primaryKey",
    @SerializedName("savingsGoals")
    val wrapper: List<SavingsGoal>
)

@Parcelize
data class SavingsGoal(
    @SerializedName("goalImageURL")
    val imageUrl: String,
    val targetAmount: Float?,
    val currentBalance: Float,
    val name: String, 
    val id: Int
) : Parcelable
```

Here is how I get data from db :

```
override fun getSavingsGoals(): Observable<SavingsGoalWrapper> =
        Observable.create { subscriber ->
            val goals = goalsDao.getGoals()
            if (goals == null) {
                subscriber.onError(NoDataException())
            } else {
                subscriber.onNext(goals)
            }
        }
```

And here is my Dao class :

```
@Dao
interface GoalsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Goals") fun getGoals(): SavingsGoalWrapper?
}
```

When I run the app, I receive following exception :

```
2021-06-01 01:28:36.051 25286-25286/com.sample.android.qapital E/BaseViewModel$sendRequest: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: goals.primaryKey (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:938)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
        at com.sample.android.qapital.data.source.local.GoalsDao_Impl$2.call(GoalsDao_Impl.java:60)
        at com.sample.android.qapital.data.source.local.GoalsDao_Impl$2.call(GoalsDao_Impl.java:55)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableFromCallable.subscribeActual(CompletableFromCallable.java:36)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2309)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.mixed.CompletableAndThenObservable.subscribeActual(CompletableAndThenObservable.java:45)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:165)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:51)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:37)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallEnqueueObservable$CallCallback.onResponse(CallEnqueueObservable.java:60)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:129)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

As you see above in says : `NOT NULL constraint failed: goals.primaryKey (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)`

How can I resolve this?

Full source code can be found : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/SavingGoals-Cache

Comment: Your issue is with [insert](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SavingGoals-Cache/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/qapital/data/source/GoalsRepository.kt#L16) not the query. You have a default value for your primary key. Primary keys must be unique.

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible that server is returning with identical SavingsGoal.id for multiple instances?

Comment: I solved the problem by creating wrapper domain class as well as db model wrapper class. In the repository I used two extension functions called asDomainModel() and asDatabaseModel() to convert from db item to domain and vice versa. As a result insert method works as expected which you mentioned in your comment. Please share your answer and I mark as accepted. Thank you @MidasLefko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with [insert](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SavingGoals-Cache/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/qapital/data/source/GoalsRepository.kt#L16) not the query. You have a default value for your primary key. Primary keys must be unique.

Alternatively, is it possible that server is returning with identical SavingsGoal.id for multiple instances?